# Convert .SCV to EPS?

Tags: vector-graphics

.SCV is an old file extension used in a program called ScanVec CASmate (I used it for vector printing 10+ years ago). Is there a way to convert this file to EPS or another vector friendly extension?

If you need to test it, the file can be accessed here (http://db.tt/aJlM1x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A vector program called
  [i-DesignR](http://www.graphtecamerica.com/software.html) by Graphtec has
  Casmate SCV on their [import list
  (PDF)](http://www.graphtecamerica.com/datasheets/i-DesignR_Import-Export_File_Types.pdf).
- I think I read somewhere
  on this site that the [Flexi
  Family](http://www.saintl.biz/Flexi8482;_FAMILY28.asp) software can do it.

Sorry, couldn't find anything for even remotely cheap, let alone free.

Comment: the Flexi sign pro software worked perfectly. Thanks!